# Experimental use of lapply() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is something related to `dplyr`, which I happened to experience while I was investigating my previous question related to `ldply`. I have been trying to understand `dplyr`. Thanks to some posts on SO, I have been learning quite a bit. But, I have a hard time to understand the following phenomenon.

```
### Here is the sample data from my previous post.

time <- seq(as.Date("2014-09-01"), by = "day", length.out = 12)
temperature <- sample(c(15:26), replace = TRUE)
weather <- sample(c("clear", "cloudy", "rain"), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
rome <- data.frame(time, temperature, weather, stringsAsFactors = F)

time <- seq(as.Date("2014-09-01"), by = "day", length.out = 12)
temperature <- sample(c(12:23), replace = TRUE)
weather <- sample(c("clear", "cloudy", "rain"), size = 12, replace = TRUE)
paris <- data.frame(time, temperature, weather, stringsAsFactors = F) 

### Assign names to each data frame and create a list
ana <- list(rome = rome, paris = paris)
```

If I want to select the 1st and 2nd column, `lapply(ana,`[`, 1:2)` will do. But, I was experimentally using `dplyr`, and I wanted to see what would happen.

```
ana %>%
lapply(., `[`, 1:2)
```

This returned the exact same result of `lapply(ana,`[`, 1:2)`, which was surprise to me. My understanding is that `dplyr` is for data frame. ana is a `list` here. There are two data frames in the list, but ana is still a list. I further experimented with some other possibilities. Since my knowledge in `dplyr` is not good enough, my syntax are probably wrong. In that case, please correct me.

```
ana %>%
    do(function(x){
    lapply(x,`[`, 1:2)
    })

ana %>%
    do({lapply(.,`[`, 1:2)
    })
```

These lines returned the following error message, which makes sense to me.

> Error in UseMethod("do") :    no applicable method for 'do' applied to
>   an object of class "list"

The question I have is why `lapply` works in the first attempt. Since I am calling a function here, I guess that `do()` is necessary. In this specific case, `dplyr` should return the error message since list should not be taken. Thank you very much for taking your time.

Comment: In this case, you are not using `dplyr`'s transformations but just the pipe operator. In this case the two definitions are identical, just the second is easier to read. If you want the result transformed into a data.frame you should try: `ana %>% lapply(., `[`, 1:2) %>% as.data.frame`

Comment: @ilir After posting the question, I had the feeling for that. Now my mind is clear. Thank you very much for your support.